# Routing PHP 5.4+ Built-in Web Server like .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, php-builtin-server

I have started using the PHP 5.6's built in web server using the following command:

```
php -S localhost:80
```

I was using WAMP Server before. And the manual also says that, if you give a router script to the above command, say like:

```
php -S localhost:80 router.php
```

We can achieve something like `.htaccess`. But I couldn't find a reliable tutorial to how to do the redirection or include. Right now, my `.htaccess` file has this contents:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*)-(.*)\.htm$ ./?page=$1&sub=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} 
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.htm$ ./?page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

What am I supposed to put in the `router.php` in order to achieve the same output that I had in the Apache Web Server? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: See [mod_rewrite.php](https://github.com/markkimsal/nanoweb-ssl/blob/master/modules/mod_rewrite.php). Albeit reimplementing two lines of regex in your router script to adapt `REQUEST_URI`+`QUERY_STRING` would certainly be simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
    $_matches = array();

    /**
     * Initialize the rewrite environment.
     */
    function initialize() {
        set_environment($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    }

    /**
     * Set important environment variables and re-parse the query string.
     * @return boolean
     */
    function finalize() {
        if (defined('REWRITER_FINALIZED')) return false;

        define('REWRITER_FINALIZED', true);

        if (\is_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])) {
            $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
        }

        if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
            $_GET = [];
            parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $_GET);
        }

        $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Adjust the server environment variables to match a given URL.
     * @param string $url
     */
    function set_environment($url) {
        $url = rtrim($url, '&?');
        $request_uri = $script_name = $url;
        $query_string = null;

        if (strpos($url, '?') > 0) {
            $script_name = substr($url, 0, strpos($url, '?'));
            $query_string = substr($url, 1 + strpos($url, '?'));
        }

        $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $request_uri;
        $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = $script_name;
        $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] = $query_string;
    }

    /**
     * Parse regular expression matches. eg. $0 or $1
     * @param string $url
     * @return string
     */
    function parse_matches($url) {        
        $replace = function($bit) {
            global $matches;
            return isset($matches[$bit[1]])
                ? $matches[$bit[1]]
                : null;
        };

        return preg_replace_callback('/\$([0-9]+)/', $replace, $url);
    }

    /**
     * Parse Apache style rewrite parameters. eg. %{QUERY_STRING}
     * @param string $url
     * @return string
     */
    function parse_parameters($url) {
        $replace = function($bit) {
            return isset($_SERVER[$bit[1]])
                ? $_SERVER[$bit[1]]
                : null;
        };
        return preg_replace_callback('/%\{([A-Z_+]+)\}/', $replace, $url);
    }

    /**
     * Change the internal url to a different url.
     * @param string $from Regular expression to match current url, or optional when used in conjunction with `test`.
     * @param string $to URL to redirect to.
     * @return boolean
     */
    function rewrite($from, $to = null) {
        if (defined('REWRITER_FINALIZED')) return false;

        $url = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];

        if (isset($to)) {
            $url = preg_replace($from, $to, $url);
        } else {
            $url = parse_matches($from);
        }

        set_environment(
            parse_parameters($url)
        );

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Compare a regular expression against the current request, store the matches for later use.
     * @return boolean
     */
    function test($expression) {
        global $matches;
        if (defined('REWRITER_FINALIZED')) return false;
        return 0 < (integer)preg_match($expression, $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], $matches);
    }

    initialize();

    // Your rewrite rules here.
    test('%/(.*)-(.*)\.htm$%') && rewrite('/?page=$1&sub=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}') && finalize();
    test('%^([^/]*)\.htm$%') && rewrite('/?page=$0&%{QUERY_STRING}') && finalize();

    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($_SERVER);
    // include index.php or something
```

I've included a bunch of 'helper' functions which will make it easier to write your rewrite rules ([borrowed here](https://gist.github.com/bjornpost/3766353)).

Comment: Lemme try this... `:)`

Comment: Hi @Bjorn, I tried `var_dump($_GET);` at the end of your script. It doesn't seem to work, or I guess I am doing something wrong. Can you please guide and explain me what to do where? Meanwhile, I will also try to decipher your script!

Comment: Hmm, what's not working? If I run the server `php -S localhost:8000 router.php`, open up `http://localhost:8000/foo-bar.htm` in my browser, I get `page=foo, sub=bar` when I `var_dump($_GET)`. I see I made a small mistake in the rewrite if you want `/foo-bar.html?moo` to work as well. Add a `&` before `%{QUERY_STRING}` to fix it.

Comment: `+1` Works buddy. Thank you so much. `:)`

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but here is a simple version:

```
<?php
    /*  Friendly Urls
        ================================================
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
        RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
        ================================================ */

    $root=__dir__;

    $uri=parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])['path'];
    $page=trim($uri,'/');   

    if (file_exists("$root/$page") && is_file("$root/$page")) {
        return false; // serve the requested resource as-is.
        exit;
    }

    $_GET['page']=$page;
    require_once 'index.php';
?>
```

This way you can use a normal `index.php` that you might have used with, say, an Apache server.

Comment: Simplest answer yet. Thanks!

Comment: Is this specific for a `GET` request?

Comment: @AbhilashKishore In the `.htaccess` version, yes, that would translate to a `GET` request. In the `router.php` version, there’s no technical reason why you can’t make it a `POST` request. However, remember that the whole point is to translate a path to a request, so I can’t see any point.

Answer (score 1):

I found a tutorial on a blog [The Reality Tunnel](http://blogs.terrorware.com/geoff/2014/06/09/rewriting-urls-for-static-files-using-phps-built-in-webserver/) which referenced a blog on [Ripeworks](http://ripeworks.com/run-wordpress-locally-using-phps-buily-in-web-server/) that contained a router script that worked for me.

The router script they gave is

```
<?php

$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
chdir($root);
$path = '/'.ltrim(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])['path'],'/');
set_include_path(get_include_path().':'.__DIR__);
if(file_exists($root.$path))
{
    if(is_dir($root.$path) && substr($path,strlen($path) - 1, 1) !== '/')
        $path = rtrim($path,'/').'/index.php';
    if(strpos($path,'.php') === false) return false;
    else {
        chdir(dirname($root.$path));
        require_once $root.$path;
    }
}else include_once 'index.php';
```